Duplicate Removal for Large Data
I am working on a retail dataset in which invoice has 250000 duplicates value . How to handle the duplicates in the data I am still trying to figure out a way to resolve the query .I was thinking to resolve it with mean median or mode

I am working on a retail dataset where i have duplicate invoice numbers ( 25 k in total rows )how to make them unique

can you show a sample of the data with duplicates? Replacing or dropping depends on the type of the data. Often times, if there are too many missing values, it may be better to just drop the column. However, if there are few missing values and it seems easy to handle them, replacing the values could greatly add to your analysis.

You can use numpy.unique. It can help you getting the uniqe array with no duplicates and also give you;

the indices of the input array that give the unique values

the indices of the unique array that reconstruct the input array

the number of times each unique value comes up in the input array


Example usage is available in the link.
